# Words and symbols

Tags: logical-deduction, word, symbols

[image]

As a word moves through a symbol (either left to right or top to bottom in a straight line), it changes according to a definite rule. Each of the four symbols has a different rule.

*Insert the missing words into the empty boxes.*

```
**This is just my assumption. I might be totally wrong.**
'White circle' represents #jumbling of alphabets# and 'dark triangle' represents #one alphabet deduction#. 
Going by that logic, there is a relation between TIFFS and STIFFS. 
However, that gives lots of outcomes for SOT. From what I assume to be the formations:

            STO     SOT     OST     OTS     TOS     TSO
            STOA    SOTH    COST    BOTS    TOSH    *
            STOB    SOTS    DOST    COTS    TOSS
            STOP    *       HOST    DOTS    TOST
            STOW    *       LOST    HOTS
                            MOST    JOTS
                            POST    LOTS
                            TOST    MOTS
                            WOST    OOTS
                                    POTS
                                    ROTS
                                    SOTS
                                    TOTS
                                    WOTS
But I cant link those words back to the 'dark circle' as all symbols have distinctly different rule pattern.
```

Certainly I am missing something somewhere. Anyone want to give this  shot?

Comment: Where you say _alphabets_, I think you mean _letters_. For most speakers of English, an _alphabet_ is a collection of all possible letters, never a single letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The symbols work in this way:
>  - black square "abcd" => "bcde"
>  - black circle "abcd" => "cbda"
>  - white circle "abcd" => "dabc"
>  - black triangle "abcd" => "dbc"
>
>  With "SEAT" ▼ "TEA" you can find "ROTS" ▼ "SOT" by applying exactly the same transformation (Assuming that the word to be found is an anagram of "SORT").
>  From there you can also find "TUBS" • "BUST" from "SORT" • "ROTS".
>  "EATS" ○ "SEAT" gives us "TIFFS" ○ "STIFF". All this has been found by applying simple changes of letters.
>  So we still have "STAR" ■ "TUBS" where we observe that it is to shift the letters of a row which gives us "SHEER" ■ "TIFFS".
>
>  [image]

Comment: I didnot quite understand how you deduced that. Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: should 'sheet' be 'sheer'?

Comment: Amitabh, I edited my answer. Hope it helps. 
@JonMark, indeed, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe square = change one, reassemble?  And full circle = change one.

> SORT -> SOFT -> SOT
>  STAR -> RUST -> BUST
>  FIFTH -> TIFFS -> STIFF

Comment: Couldn't it be SORT->SOOT->SOT as well then?

Comment: @AmitabhGhosh Yea i guess, didn't knew this word before.